# C# Object Binary Serialization

Tags: c#, string, serialization, binaryformatter

I want to make a binary serialize of an object and the result to save it in a database.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "something";

MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(memorystream, person);
```

How can I transform memorystream in a string type to be saved in database, and after this to be able to deserialize the object?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What you're *really* asking for is a safe way of representing arbitrary binary data as text and then converting it back again. The fact that it stores a serialized object is irrelevant.

The answer is almost to use Base 64 (e.g. [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)). Do *not* use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` or anything similar - your binary data is *not* encoded text data, and shouldn't be treated as such.

However, does your database not have a data type for binary data? Check for BLOB, IMAGE and BINARY types...

Comment: bytes to string --- needs some Encoding.

Comment: @loneshark99: I don't understand your comment at all. If this is arbitrary binary data - rather than encoded text - then using an `Encoding` would be precisely the *wrong* approach.

Comment: I am learning , but I am wondering why Encoding is not the right approach and ToBase64String is.

Comment: @loneshark99: Because an `Encoding` is designed for data that is inherently textual - it converts that text to binary data, whereas base64 and hex are designed for representing inherently binary arbitrary data as text without losing information.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense!. I always get confused about encoding. Thank you!!

Answer (score 45):

Here's the sample. TData must be marked [Serializable] and all fields type also.

```
    private static TData DeserializeFromString<TData>(string settings)
    {
        byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(settings);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(b))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (TData)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    private static string SerializeToString<TData>(TData settings)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, settings);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19):

```
//-------write to database-------------------------
Person person = new Person();
person.name = "Firstnm  Lastnm";
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(); 
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(memorystream, person);
byte[] yourBytesToDb = memorystream.ToArray();
//here you write yourBytesToDb to database


//----------read from database---------------------
//here you read from database binary data into yourBytesFromDb
MemoryStream memorystreamd = new MemoryStream(yourBytesFromDb);
BinaryFormatter bfd = new BinaryFormatter();
Person deserializedperson = bfd.Deserialize(memorystreamd) as Person;
```

Comment: There should be a `using` around the `MemoryStream`

Comment: There is a Warning for .Net5.0 and a few other flavors: "The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing. Applications should stop using BinaryFormatter as soon as possible, even if they believe the data they're processing to be trustworthy. BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide

Answer (score 14):

I used something like this

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, Person);
memoryStream.Flush();
memoryStream.Position = 0;
string value = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: You don't need to rewind a MemoryStream before calling ToArray - it returns the whole stream's data regardless of the current position. Likewise Flush doesn't do anything on a MemoryStream, although it's a good idea for streams in general.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, **don't** save the data as string to the database, there are `blob` fields available to store binary data.

If you really need to have the data as string, you'll need to convert your byte[] to a string using base64 encoding, and to grab the byte[] from a string use decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not looked into converting the memorystream into a base64hex string to be put into the database?

```
 byte[] mStream = memorystream.ToArray();
 string sConvertdHex = System.Convert.ToBase64String(mStream)
```

Then you can dump the contents sConvertdHex to the database. To deserialize it you need to do the reverse

```
 byte[] mData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(...)
```

then deserialize mData back to your object.