# How to Convert system.windows.controls.image to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I need to convert `System.Windows.Controls.Image` to `byte[]`.

How to do it ?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to convert a 'system.windows.controls.image' and not simply the 'System.Drawing.Image' that it displays instead?

Comment: @Brian It's WPF, so the class that contains the actual image is `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` and not `System.Drawing.Image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you answer my query above that you are actually trying to convert an image into a byte array rather than an image control into a byte array here is the code to do so;

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: 1) You have a WinForms solution, not a WPF solution 2) Gif is no general purpose image format since it only supports 8bit images. I'd use png instead.

Comment: Wouldn't that return a byte[] with a GIF in it? It feels unlikely that that is what he wants.

Comment: @codeinchaos - Where does the question mention anything about WPF?

Comment: It says `system.windows.controls.image`. And that's a WPF class.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to convert an object to a byte array, you may want to use binary serialization. This will generate a memory stream from which you can extract a byte array.

You may start with this [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749044/c-object-binary-serialization)

Comment: IMO there are few uses where `BinaryFormatter` is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/myImage.jpg");
img.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
byte[] arr;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
      var bmp = img.Source as BitmapImage;
      JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
      encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
      encoder.Save(ms);
      arr = ms.ToArray();
}
```