# How to get Binary equivalent of BLOB data type in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am using C# for front end and Oracle as a database. I have a BLOB type field in a table and is used to contain images. What I actually need to do is that whenever a record in table doesn't contain any image I want to show default pic for that particular record in front end. For that purpose can I get a binary format of that default image(without saving that image with a dummy record) after saving it temporarily in database, and then using that binary format in query to show default pic when the image doesn't exists for any record. What I am getting now is :

```
 SELECT EMP_IMG FROM Employee_Master WHERE EMP_CODE = 1234
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 (BLOB)
```

Comment: So... is the problem that your command line tool doesn't show BLOB contents?

Answer (score 0):

Look into byte[]; use Binary Serializer to get the byte[] version of the object.
See this: [C# Object Binary Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749044/c-sharp-object-binary-serialization)

Comment: hi @Matt I have used following line in front end but unable to get values in a single line instead in .NET values are shown indexed wise  `image = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();`