# Serialize object into string

Tags: c#, string, serialization, stream, arrays

I am trying to serialize a class to be sent to a server where the server will use that object.  I am using Microsoft's example of an asynchronous client/server setup for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx  I am using the binary formatter.

To test this, I am using this class:

```
[Serializable]
class Class1
{
    public int x = 10;
    public string banana = "banana";

}
```

and attempting to serialize it with:

```
Class1 example = new Class1();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, example);
```

in order to send it to the server, I need to send a string:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream );
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
server.Send(text);
stream.Close();
```

but this doesn't work.  I have tried converting the stream to a byte[] as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749044/c-sharp-object-binary-serialization) but I keep getting a `Stream was unreadable` exception when testing this in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Class1 example = new Class1();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   formatter.Serialize(ms, example);

   ms.Position = 0;
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
   String text = sr.ReadToEnd();

   server.Send(text);
}
```

I think that the part that got missed is resetting the position of MemoryStream to be able to read (think of it as rewinding for playback after recording)