# Why do I need to flush and set the stream position to 0 in this serialization snippet?

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, flush

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749044/c-sharp-object-binary-serialization):

```
    private static string SerializeToString<T>(T value)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, value);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private static T DeserializeFromString<T>(string data)
    {
        byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(b)) {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

Why do I need to flush and set the position to 0 in the serialize method, and seek in the deserialize method?

I removed them, they didn't affect anything.

I know that flushing means write whatever that's in the stream immediately.

But I don't know if it's necessary here... also not sure about the position and seek.

Comment: Why are you using such an old example? Did you have a specific requirement to use the old BinaryFormatter? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To be honest I didn't notice the date of that question. I'm just messing around with streams and string serialization when I came across that question. I'm interested in Binary serialization atm, I know BF is slow, there's protobuf-net - I read that it's fast but requires a lot of manual setup ... don't mean to ask another Q, but since you asked, maybe you have some other serializers recommendations?

Comment: Just stick with Data Contract Serialization until you _need_ something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These samples contain unecessary code. The documentation for MemoryStream.ToArray ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx)) explicitly states that:

> Writes the stream contents to a byte array, regardless of the Position
>   property.

Thus, we clearly don't need to set position. The flush is more debatable. It's very, very unlikely that memory stream would buffer under the hood, since it's just writing to a memory buffer anyway. However, I'm not sure that it's documented anywhere that memory stream won't buffer, so Flush() might be reasonable since we're calling ToArray() before disposing the stream. Another approach would be to call ToArray() outside the using block (we'd have to move the declaration of the variable out as well). This will work because ToArray() states that:

> This method works when the MemoryStream is closed.

On the read side, you are creating a new stream, which starts at position 0 by default. Thus, there's no need for the Seek call.

Comment: Flushing does bugger all. The .net source can [verify this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,1a4dcb744a23ba6f)